# how to setup multiple background on one activity randomly

Tags: java, android, xml, background, launcher

i need to know how to setup background randomly on one activity,
'android:background="@drawable/backG"' only show one image 
the background come randomly with the launch of the application, and it keep on showing until the user quit the app, and when he reopen it, it will show a new background
note : i have only one activity in my project
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should use **Java** code to make this.
For example, you have **RelativeLayout** is the main layout in your activity
You should use

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.rLayout);
Resources res = getResources(); //resource handle
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newImage); //new Image that was added to the res folder
rLayout.setBackground(drawable);
```

For random background: you create an array that contains all you images background
and use the code below for random position

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomPositionInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(10); // it will generate position in 0 - 10
```

Hope this help